# inputting a letter into jest test with enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, jsx, enzyme

I have tried many ways to input a letter into my input element in jest+enzyme:

```
it('should change input text and state with it', () => {
  const input = wrap.find('input')
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  //console.log(input.debug()) <input value="name" onChange={[Function]} />
  input.simulate('change', {event: {target: {value: 'namea'}}})
  //input.simulate('keydown', { which: 'a'})
  expect(wrap.state('value')).toBe('namea')
  //expect(input.props().value).toBe('namea')
})
//and the wrap
  const wrap = mount(
   <AddTodo addTodo={spy} />
  ) //still occurs with shallow
```

When i run the code, i get the error: Expected: 'namea' Received: 'name'
My component is as so:
https://github.com/conradkay/todo-app-jest-flow-router-react-redux/blob/master/src/addTodo/addTodo.jsx

Comment: I have now figured out that the onChange event is now occuring, so the error is most likely in:
`
  handleChange = (event: SyntheticKeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    //this.setState({value: event.currentTarget.value})
    this.setState({value: 'namea'})
  }

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that happens when you handle events in a certain way using flow. To correct this error, use:

```
  handleChange = ({target}: SyntheticInputEvent<>) => {
    this.setState({value: target.value})
  }
  and:
  input.simulate('change', {target: {value: 'namea'}})
  expect(wrap.state('value')).toBe('namea')
```